# Get Current Logged Username in my app

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

I would like to get the current logged in username and display it my frontend. 
Currently I have a function called GetCurrentUser()  that gets called when a button is clicked.

```
<button type="submit" onclick="GetCurrentUser()" style="margin-left: 15px;margin-top:10px; margin-bottom: 5px;background-color: black; "value="Submit">Save Selections</button><br>

function GetCurrentUser() {
var usrName ="@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString()";
//var usrName = '<%HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>';
//document.getElementById("UserName").innerHTML = usrName;
console.log(usrName);}
```

I get the follwoingoutput in my console log--> @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Comment: Did you try `<%=`?

Comment: like this var usrName = <%HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>; ? @taha Paksu

Comment: `var usrName = "<%=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>";`

Comment: This is what I see when I tried it in my console log
GetCurrentUserName.js:5 <%HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>

Comment: Add an `=` after the `<%`.

Comment: I tired it and it doesn't work.

Comment: I am thinking I have to write in a CS file and then send it to JS file. Not sure if I can just do it explicitly in JS.

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeing the literal output of "HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name " then your JS function is generated client side after you have lost server context.

Couple options for you:

1. Call back to your controller via ajax to get the username
2. Store the username in a read only field on page load (kinda like setting a form value) and retrieve the value via jquery or js on function call
3. Assign the username on page load to a global js element and just use that element in your function.

Here is an example of 2 and 3. I don't think you should worry about #1 until you fully understand why your issue is happening in the first place:

```
    <div class="btn btn-info" onclick="GetCurrentUser()" style="margin-left: 15px;margin-top:10px; margin-bottom: 5px;background-color: black; " value="Submit">Save Selections</div><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="method2" id="method2" value="@System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name">
    @section scripts {
        <script>
            var globalSettingMethod = '@System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name';
            function GetCurrentUser() {
                alert(globalSettingMethod);
                alert($('#method2').val());
            }
        </script>
    }
```

Comment: @rabyusbeef update answer with most popular methods used.

Comment: @rabyusbeef I updated my answer with the three most popular ways of doing what you are trying to do. I then have added example of the two easier ways of doing it.

Comment: I tried it the suggestion but it did not work but returned '@System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name'

Comment: No, you just plugged in the code hoping it would work without understanding the real problem. You've lost server side context at the point in time when you are trying to assign the value in js. IE: When you are assigning value to your js element, it is already past the razor engine which would catch and process that value, instead the script has already been passed over client side and js is assigning the literal value. It has to do with the structure of how you are serving up your script,

Answer (score 1):

I could get the user logged in by passing the script at the end of the document.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Example.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    </form>
    <script>
        var loggedUser = "<%: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope you find it useful.